# Speech to text conversion

Tags: google-api, speech-to-text

I am working on the speech to text process for audio file. I am using google API to convert calls into text. For the conversion process I am using google cloud storage but I am getting the error i.e. "Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started" again and again.

Although I have created a json file of google credential and after running that file it is working. But when I import the credential file in my code it shows the same bug which mentioned above.

Can anybody please help me to recover this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. This will be used by the client library in the programming language you're using.

linux: 
`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/<username>/path-to-json"`

windows (PowerShell): 
`$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\<username>\path-to-json"`

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries